# How to get Firestore document snapshots stream where id is emitted by other stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, rxdart

I'd like to create a stream of `DocumentSnapshots` from Firestore where id of the document can be supplied from another stream.

My AuthRepository emits user id whenever this id changes (e.g. after logging in or out).

Let's say it looks like this:

```dart
  Stream<String> get userId => _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map((user) {
        if (user != null)
          return user.uid;
        else {
          return null;
        }
      });
```

Then I want to use this stream to obtain a `DocumentSnapshot` stream from Firestore e.g. in form of `_firestore.document('users/$id').snapshots()`:

```dart
  // We have access to Firestore here 
  final Firestore _firestore;

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get _usersSnapshotsStream {
    // What should I use here? asyncExpand? map? transform?
    return _authRepository.userId.map((id) {
       // I want to access _firestore.document('users/$id').snapshots()

    });
  }
```

What stream operation should I perform in `_usersSnapshotsStream` to always get the latest document for given user id supplied from other stream?